# How to set the first continuous combobox invisible in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, filter, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to add an OR feature in the Continuous Filter Form and as you can see the first combobox shows up which I don't want it to show. Ideally, it should show only when the user wants the second row search option not in the first row filter. I have only OR in the combobox. Thanks for your help and let me know if you need any clarification! 
[image]

Comment: I got the visible and invisible part going with this code: `Private Sub Criteria_AfterUpdate()
 If Me.Criteria.Column(2) = True And filterDict.Exists(Criteria.Value) Then
    Me.CmbOperator.visible = False
        Else
    Me.CmbOperator.visible = True
        End If
    Me.CmbOperator.Requery
End Sub` but my problem is it shouldn't show on the first row of filter where First Name is selected. Is there any way to say "if the form is on continuous then combobox should be visible"? Or in other words if there's the second row shows then show the comobobox on the second row not the first row?

Comment: You can't ever get the combobox to not show on the first row ONLY, since it's a continuous form. You can control user input (my answer) or control visibility (craig's answer) but it's all or nothing. Anything else will require a different form design that doesn't take advantage of continuous forms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous form controls are all or nothing. If it's visible, it's visible in all rows, if invisible, it's invisible in all rows. There's nothing you can do about that.

You have four options (in order of complexity):

First Option:
The "On Current" event of the form happens when a user moves from one row to another inside the continuous form. you can add an IF statement to that event that disables the first box if the user has moved to the first row.

Second Option:
Have a fixed amount of filter boxes, and don't let the user pass the limit

Third Option:
Have a fixed amount of filter boxes, but make a "forward" and "back" buttons that will change what data the filter boxes link to, effectively making a 'custom' continuous form

Fourth Option:
Dynamically create the textboxes programatically (not recommended)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative options! I like your first option but how do I programmatically tell this whenever user decides to move from one to another rows?

Comment: As soon as a user selects any element within a row, the On Current event will fire. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214515%28v=office.12%29.aspx 

 That way you know you are on a new row, and all the controls/ records of the underlying table within the continuous form that you access will be from the new row. So what you could do is, for example, check the PK of the underlying table and then you know what row you're on, and can enable or disable the combobox accordingly.

Comment: Again, this will enable/disable the combo box in all of the rows but at least when the user selects a different row you can enable it again.

Comment: If it were me, I'd make the combo box cmbOperator build off what serakfalcon was leading to and have 3 options: "IF", "OR" and "AND".
The "IF" would be the default only on the first row (New entry) otherwise it would default to "OR".  The user could also select "AND" if desired.  You would need to put in a bit of logic to verify the user didn't select "IF" again though.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default 'Visible' property to 'No' and then Reset it to 'Yes' when a second criteria is selected.  This will populate the whole column though, just so you know.